# Nonparametric approach for regression with a quadratic fit

Tags: model, nonparametric-regression

I'm trying to figure out which nonparametric test I should run on my data.

My data has residuals that are not normal, so I cannot run a linear regression unless I log transform it. However, log transforming my data would make it difficult to interpret a quadratic model, so I need to run a nonparametric test similar to regression.

I'm trying to compare 2 models and determine which has a better fit - a linear model (y~x) or a quadratic model (y~x+x^2). Which nonparametric approach similar to regression should I use to construct each model?

Comment: Can you describe your response variable? Can you describe how the quadratic model arises? (e.g. does it come from theory? Or is its introduction more prosaic?)  Since you already looked at residuals (so the '*don't choose analyses based on looking at the sample*'-horse has already bolted), what did they look like?

Comment: Would you please post the data, or a link to the data?

Comment: Our DV is a measure of executive function and our IV is cortisol. We are checking for a quadratic fit because research has suggested that as cortisol increases, so does performance on cognitive tasks up til a threshold. Once that threshold is reached, performance begins to decrease again as there is too much cortisol in the system. The QQ plot looks like a smooth zigzag, going in a positive direction.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the dependent variable (DV) is continuous and that the other assumptions of linear regression are met, you could try any sort of robust regression (as far as I know, MM estimation seems to be the currently favored method) or quantile regression (which makes no assumptions about the residuals).  With quantile regression, you'd be analyzing the median (or other quantiles) rather than the mean, but if the distribution of your DV is symmetric, that shouldn't be a problem.

Also, I'd consider looking at a model with splines rather than just linear and quadratic effects, unless there is strong theoretical reason to think that a quadratic fit is correct.